# How to get one result from 3 tables in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need one result from 3 tables. How do I do that in a stored procedure?

Here are my 3 tables:
[image: 3 SQL tables]

Here is the result I want:

[image: Result from 3 SWL tables]

I have try many code but nothing works, example:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, c.name 
FROM TableA AS a, TableB as b, TableC as c
WHERE a.idTableB = b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `Coalesce()` to replace NULLs with empty strings in case that's better for you :

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name AS nameTableA,
  Coalesce(b.name,'') AS nameTableB,
  Coalesce(c.name,'') AS nameTableC
FROM TableA AS a
  LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.idTableB = b.id 
  LEFT JOIN TableC AS c ON b.idTableC = c.id
```

Comment: That is not a problem. In my code I use: 'if (!reader.IsDBNull(3))
          X.nameTableC = reader.GetString(3);'

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetResultSet
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT A.ID 
        ,A.Name   AS nameTableA
        ,B.Name   AS nameTableB
        ,C.Name   AS nameTableC
  FROM TABLEA A LEFT JOIN TABLEB B
  ON A.idTableB = B.ID
  LEFT JOIN TABLEC C
  ON C.idTableC = C.ID

END
```

**Call Procedure**

```
EXECUTE dbo.usp_GetResultSet
```